# short url's using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url

I want to make short url's in my web for ex:

change this url:

> www.site.com/somepage.php
>
> www.site.com/text.php?id=123

to this:

> www.site.com/somepage
>
> www.site.com/text/123

I tried alot of example from answers here and nothing work, I dont konw what I'm doing worng.

my default htaccess file is:

```
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
    suPHP_ConfigPath /home/user/php.ini
    <Files php.ini>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
</IfModule>
# Use PHP5 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php
```

What I need to do for making it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define a rule and active the URL Rewriting :

```
#URL Rewriting  
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^somepage$ /somepage.php [L]

#Your code
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
    suPHP_ConfigPath /home/user/php.ini
    <Files php.ini>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
</IfModule>
# Use PHP5 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php
```

Comment: Is the URL rewriting active on your server ? Search "mod_rewrite" on you phpinfo(), to know

Comment: yes its active, I dont konw what I'm doing worng. can you post here the full htaccsess file like it should be? i tried this:   <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
 suPHP_ConfigPath /home/username/php.ini
 <Files php.ini>
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
 </Files>
</IfModule>
# Use PHP5 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^home$ /home.php [L]

Comment: I updated my answer, but what is your error ? Can you screenshot ?

Comment: first ty, now its work when i enter domain.com/home its go to domain.com/home.php. but how can i make it work gor somthing like this too: domain.com/page/2 -> domain.com/page?id=2  ? my code now is this: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]

Comment: It's something like this, try : RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)$ page.php?id=$1 [L]

Comment: ty, its work with few changes. can I make a rule that will active only in none of the rule before him happen?

Comment: No I don't think (or I don't know sorry). Glad to see it's working for you ;)